# Powerbuilder Datawindow Error

Tags: powerbuilder

Help, our team upgraded/changed our Laptops from Windows XP to Windows 7 64 Bit, that came with the laptop itself. its therefore licensed and cannot be downgraded.

When using a datawindow and adding the second argument

I am getting Column 2 has an invalid name and/or length error...

I also opened my other already made Datawindow from the previous laptop that has multiple arguments. every 2 args. the name is missing.. but when you delete the top part. you can see the invisible argument is there.

Any patch I need to install. I cannot proceed with my programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, for me none of the above mentioned method was working, but I had a workaround. I added the first parameter as usual with the datawindow painter. My first parameter name: "username" is a string. I would like to add a second parameter: "password". For this I made the following steps:

1. Open the datawindow (double click on the datawindow object)
2. Click on Data source toolbar button
3. Select Design/Convert to syntax
4. Click back and save the datawindow

After that open the datawindow source:

1. Right click on the datawindow object
2. Edit source
3. Search for string like: arguments=(("
4. In my case it was: arguments=(("username", string))
5. Add the second argument this way (in my case): arguments=(("username", string),("password", string))

So you need to simply copy the first argument after a comma. Of course you have to give a name and a type for the second argument like in my example!

Br. Gábor

Comment: I can say that this is the right answer as this was the way I did it before. I mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround posted by @Slapout didn't work for me. I did however find a [KB article](http://search.sybase.com/kbx/solvedcases?id_number=11693413) on Sybase's website that helped:

> It appears that all HP computer systems come preloaded with a program called Digital Persona. This program is used by the finger print scanner built into many of their laptop systems. They also install it on desktop machines. There is a service created called either "Authentication Service" or "Biometric Authentication Service." These services must be stopped in order for the retrieval argument error to be
>   resolved.
>
> On the HP Elitebook 2740p stopping the service for the touch pad called "Tablet PC Input Service" will resolve the retrieval argument error.
>
> Another piece of software to look for is DisplayFusion multi-monitor tool. Killing that process will also resolve the problem.

I couldn't find any services with them names, but I did find DpAgent.exe and a few variations thereof, in the task manager process list. Killing them immediately fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Here's the workaround:

Create a third argument under the second one. Give it the exact same name and type of the second argument. Then delete the second argument and press OK.

Comment: yep i was already doing that. the problem is i have to do it everytime I open the argument to add something. plus what if i have like 10+ arguments

Answer (score 0):

This problem could also be caused by entering Unity Mode in VMWare Workstation. As soon as Unity Mode is turned on, the error appears when a second retrieval argument is added.

If a second retrieval argument already exists, then it will actually appear as blank until Unity Mode is exited.

This does not appear to be an issue if VMWare is running in windowed mode, full screen mode, or full screen mode spanned across multiple monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue but this is more of compatibility issue. You need to go to properties page of the Shortcut and go to compatibility tab select "Run this program compatibility mode for - Windows XP (Service pack 3)" - This should solve your issue.

Hope this will help.

Regards,

Ranjith

Comment: Thanks, it would be a good reference. But this would be helpful back in 2012 :) thanks anyway and it will be good for others who might need it. I also think I tried that because I used to do that in StarCraft games but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Here's the workaround:

Create a third argument under the second one. Give it the exact same name and type of the second argument. Then delete the second argument and press OK.